# VB.NET site is not displaying the right data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have a textbox where a user enters a code that is connected to their account. It will then display a welcome message in place of the textbox where they entered their information. It used to work up until I added more code for it to query another database. That ended up messing up my page and since I have deleted that code, I must've forgotten something, or maybe my code was messy to begin with....but now my welcome message is always the wrong person's name. In fact, no matter what code you type in, it displays the same person's name. This person doesn't even have a code in the database. I tried adding `IS NOT NULL` and `IS LIKE 'B%'` so that it doesn't show that person's name, but it doesn't help.

When I do the queries in SQL Server, I get the results that I want. Can someone help me find out what is wrong with my page that isn't allowing the name to display? When I debug, GetAccountName shows that it has grabbed the correct user name and put it into the Session variables.

When it goes back to the custom validator, lblIB.Text never gets information to display the welcome message so it just grabs the first thing in the database, which is always wrong.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<div id="ib">
    <asp:Label ID="IBText" runat="server" Text="Enter your IB code here:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IBTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="IBTextBoxButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="IBTextBox" ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
 </div><!-- end ib div -->


Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class MasterPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ib As String = String.Empty
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Request.QueryString("IB") IsNot Nothing Then
            ib = Request.QueryString("IB")
            Session("IB") = True
        End If
        If Session("IB") Is Nothing Then
            'show textbox
            IBText.Visible = True
            IBTextBox.Visible = True
            IBTextBoxButton.Visible = True
        Else
            'call function
            GetSessionValues(ib)

        End If
    End If
  End Sub
  Protected Function GetSessionValues(ByVal Code As String) As Boolean
    Dim FirstName As String = String.Empty
    Dim LastName As String = String.Empty

    If GetAccountName(Code, FirstName, LastName) Then
        'set session variables
        Session("First_Name") = FirstName
        Session("Last_Name") = LastName

        'hide textbox
        IBText.Visible = False
        IBTextBox.Visible = False
        IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
        'args.IsValid = True
        'show welcome message to user if IB code exists in database
        lblIB.Visible = True
        lblIB.Text = "Welcome, " + Session("First_Name") + " " + Session("Last_Name") + "."
        Return True
    Else
        'IB code not found
        'args.IsValid = False
        'shows error message in red
        lblIB.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblIB.Text = "Account not found, please try again."
        Return False
    End If
  End Function

  Private Function GetAccountName(ByVal BAccount As String, ByRef FirstName As String, ByRef LastName As String) As Boolean
    'sql statement for baccount information
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT BAccount, First_Name, Last_Name 
    FROM IB 
    INNER JOIN IB_BUISNESS_INFORMATION ON (IB.IB_ID = IB_BUISNESS_INFORMATION.IB_ID)
    WHERE BAccount = @BAccount"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BAccount", BAccount)
            conn.Open()
            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If (rdr.Read) Then
                    FirstName = rdr("First_Name").ToString()
                    LastName = rdr("Last_Name").ToString()
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
  End Function

  Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
    'declare variables
    Dim FirstName As String = String.Empty
    Dim LastName As String = String.Empty

    If (Not GetSessionValues(args.Value)) Then
        args.IsValid = False
    Else
        args.IsValid = True
    End If

    If GetAccountName(args.Value, FirstName, LastName) Then
        'set session variables
        Session("First_Name") = FirstName
        Session("Last_Name") = LastName

        'hide textbox
        IBText.Visible = False
        IBTextBox.Visible = False
        IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
        args.IsValid = True
        'show welcome message to user if IB code exists in database
        lblIB.Visible = True
        lblIB.Text = "Welcome, " + Session("First_Name") + " " + Session("Last_Name") + "."
    Else
        'IB code not found
        args.IsValid = False
        'shows error message in red
        lblIB.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblIB.Text = "Account not found, please try again."
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub IBTextBoxButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles IBTextBoxButton.Click
    If Page.IsValid Then
        'declare variables
        Dim LSD As String = String.Empty
        Dim LSC As String = String.Empty
        Session("IB") = IBTextBox.Text
        Dim IB As String = Session("IB")
        'add session variable
        If GetCompanyName(LSD) Then
            Session("LSD") = LSD
        Else
            'no data found
        End If
        'add session variable
        If GetWebsite(LSC) Then
            Session("LSC") = LSC
        Else
            'no data found
        End If
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
    End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove** the following line of code.  If GetAccountName works like how you say it does, it will solve your problem.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

Comment: I removed it and it looks fine now. The correct name is being shown, there must be something wrong with my session though, because that name is not being held in the session from page to page.

Comment: Yep, look at your Page_Load logic.  Use a breakpoint if you have to.

Comment: Do I need to add session code to every single page or is it supposed to work on every page if I put it on the master page? Because right now I have it on the master page and this is the only one it works on.

Comment: It will work on all pages by having it in the Master Page.  The bug is pretty obvious.  Pay close attention to your logic in the Page Load event handler and you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsPostBack` method in your `pageload` event of all pages and close all session variables created on each page at the end of your page load event.